# Como fazer push de pasta local para GitHub

Tags: git, github, versionamento

Gostaria de fazer um push de um repositório local para meu GitHub. Para isso fiz o procedimento padrão:

```
git clone <chave ssh>
```

Até ai tudo maravilha, ele criou uma cópia do repositório do GiHub localmente. Dentro desse repositório tem uma pasta com arquivos que também quero mandar para o repositório correspondente no GitHub. Fiz `add` e `commit` da pasta e em seguida fiz um `push` para o repositório no GitHub, mas aparentemente ele só adiciona a pasta e não seu arquivos. Naveguei até a pasta e fiz o mesmo procedimento anterior e obtive o seguinte output:

```
$ git push origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Alguma sugestão de como fazer o `push` desses arquivos?

Comment: Quando você digita `git status` os arquivos do tal diretório em verde? Se não aparecerem, você consegue adicioná-los digitando `git add diretório/nome_do_arquivo`?

Comment: Nesse diretório, existe a pasta .git? Então dentro dela existe um arquivo chamado `config`. Olhe nesse arquivo e veja se tem um repositório remote chamado `origin` e se tem um branch `master`.

Outra coisa, eu sempre adiciono a partir da pasta raiz do repositório e uso o `add --all`.

Outra coisa, fez upload da chave para o github? De uma olhada em https://github.com/settings/ssh

Comment: Verifique se você fez o clone com as suas credenciais do github. É possível que você tenha feito o clone com o endereço para usuário anônimo e não te permissões de escrita lá. Vale lembrar também de conferir se sua chave pública está cadastrada nas suas configurações do github.

Comment: Conforme vejo os colegas acima comentando, deduzo que está inciando com o versionamento utilizando o git com o github.

recomendo o site https://try.github.io/ para praticar e melhorar o conhecimento sobre git.

Answer (score 7):

Tive um problema muito semelhante quando iniciei os versionamentos com o Git + GitHub, e esse problema ocorria quando o diretório remoto não era criado para o 'origin'.

Para tal é necessário o seguinte comando:

```
git remote add origin [endereco-do-repositorio]
```

O `git clone` garante apenas uma cópia do repositório. Para maiores informações pode acessar o [Help do GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote).

Answer (score 1):

Somente complementando a resposta do soaresfelipe:

`git remote add origin <URL>` irá adicionar o endereço aos seus repositorios remotos (oque deve ser suficiente em seu caso). Mas, aconselho a utilizar o `git add -A` na pasta raiz do seu repositorio depois, sim o `git commit` antes de fazer o push, pois aparentemente você não está comitando todos os arquivos.

Caso tenha dúvida você pode usar o `git log` para verificar quais commits ja foram feitos.

Comment: Fiz o seguinte:  git remote add origin <URL>, ai depois disso dê uma olha no arquivo .git/config se aparece a tags [remote "origin"] e embaixo a tag [branch "master"].             Se estiver tudo certo, adciona os arquivo que deseja enviar com $ git add [arquivos], em seguinda da um commit e depois dar um push. Agora o seu arquivos já estarão desponivel no gitbhub.

Answer (score 0):

Digita para verificar se está com algum repositório:

```
 git remote -v
```

Se sim irá aparecer algo assim:

```
origin  git@bitbucket.org:<seu_usuario>/sua_app.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:<seu_usuario>/sua_app.git (push)
```

Se não aparecer e informar q não existe algum repositório você terá que adicionar algum. Se no caso for GitHub:

Clicar no ícono **+ > Novo repositório** (isso está situado no menu ao lado da foto de seu usuário).

Daí é só preencher os dados como nome do repositório, se vai elegir do tipo publico ou privado. Daí o GitHub vai informado o que necessita, é só acompanhar.

Answer (score 0):

Isso aconteceu porque você não fez o link entre seu repositório local e o repositório que está no GitHub.

Use o comando `git remote add <apelido> <link-do-repositório-github>`, substituindo o que está entre os símbolos `<>`.

É comum usarmos por padrão o apelido `origin` pro repositório remoto.

Para verificar se o link foi corretamente criado use `git remote` e o git te informará o nome do repositório remoto que o seu local está apontando.

Answer (score 0):

O meu problema talvez seja parecido com o seu. O meu git estava configurado em HTTP. Use o comando para visualizar a sua configuração git remote -v e caso confirme exclua com o comando git remote remove origin,e depois faça o processo do git remote add, repita novamente git remote -v para visualizar se realmente foi alterado. No meu deu certo. Feliz da vida kkkk

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).